# How to integrate Grunt with Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests, asset-pipeline, gruntjs

The question is: how do you integrate Rails with Grunt?

Just a quick brainstorm and I figured out that I **need**:

- PhanomJS
- Jasmine
- JSHint / JSLint

I **do not need** or I don't know if I need (it's up to Rails) :)

- minification
- uglification (obfuscation)
- concatenation

How do I integrate it with an existing Rails app? What steps shoud I take in order to make it work? Where should Grunt files / config reside?
And the final question: does it intefere with Rails assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice
+
https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine

or

https://github.com/modeset/teabag

Both integrate nicely with assets pipeline and coffee script.